# Android SDK IDE configuration (cannot highlight all instances of a variable)

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-2.1

In the Android SDK IDE, in the code view, if we bring the typing pointer at the location of a  variable, all the other references to that variable gets highlighted, as shown

[image]

For some reason, this has stopped happening in my computer. It was enabled by default before, but suddenly it stopped happing, and I have no idea what caused it. If I hover the mouse pointer over a variable or class name it just shows the tooltip window, and if I bring the typing pointer at the variable's location then nothing happens. What is the name for this highlighting feature, and how do I re-enable it?

Incidentally, how do I view my android sdk version? The About ADT button says Build v22.0.1-685705, but the question tags here only show sdk2.1, 2.2 and 2.3, so i'm sure it hasn't reached version 22 yet. Or does this mean I have version 2.2?

Comment: Is this "Android SDK" IDE... Eclipse? IntelliJ IDEA? Android Studio? I believe that (for Eclipse) it is merely a setting.. I'm looking for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse, you can turn this (search highlighting) on or off by using the "Toggle Mark Occurrences (Alt + Shift + O). Visually, the control button for this looks like a yellow highlighter.

As for "SDK Version"... in Eclipse, go to Window > Android SDK Manager.
This opens up a window with several details related to your SDK version and supported libraries, files, etc. Near the top, you should see Tools > Android SDK Tools. Your version might be 22.0.5 (as an example). This is the SDK Tools revision number. You should keep it up-to-date periodically throughout the year (check monthly if you wish).

The SDK Tools version number (22.0.5) does not mean "2.2" - this 2.2 number refers to the Android API version..

Please see this [**google link**](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) for a correlation between SDK Version and API version. The AndroidManifest calls it "minSdkVersion" so i can see where this can be confusing.

Comment: The search highlighting feature was On; it turns out that the problem was only specific to this instance of the SDK, closing and then restarting the IDE solved the problem. thank you for your help.